# Set SharePoint Search Query Result Source in JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-jsom, sharepoint-search

I am setting the result source level to 'SPSite' as I want to use the result source defined at site collection level. But it does not work. Is 'SPSite' a valid argument in JSOM?

```
let query = new Search.KeywordQuery(ctx);

// set Source Name
query.get_properties().set_item('SourceName', 'Result Source Name');
// set Source Level
query.get_properties().set_item('SourceLevel', 'SPSite');
```

If I set the source level to 'SPSiteSubscription', it successfully use the tenant level result source.

Answer (score 1):

I was stumped at same spot for awhile. Adding a refiner filter to the query did the trick for me and the situation I was in. Might be useful to you as well.

```
    // add refiner(s)
    keywordQuery.set_refiners("SPSiteURL");

    // add the returned columns
    var properties = keywordQuery.get_selectProperties();
    properties.add('SPWebUrl');                 // site this comes from

    // below is how to build the refinement filter to add to the keywordquery
    var filterCollection = keywordQuery.get_refinementFilters();

    // add scope filter, can be mannualy or can grab the webUrl from the client context
    // var filter = Modifier + ':"' + RefinementToken(or value) + '"';
    filterCollection.add('SPSiteURL:"'+webUrl+'"');
```